# how can i apply featherlight in a dropdown menu?

Tags: featherlight.js

I am asking because i could not find on github project suggestions, anyway i would like know how can I apply this effect in a  or a dropdown menu its is possible? maybe you guys can include this example too?

plugin: https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight/

my html:

```
<select>
    <option>Apples</option>
    <option selected>Pineapples</option>
    <option>Chocklate</option>
    <option>Pancakes</option>
</select>

<div class="dropdown pull-right">
          <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">main
          <span class="caret"></span></button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" >
            <li><a href="#">test1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">test2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">test3</a></li>
          </ul>
</div>
```

thank you.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do nor what you tried to have it work.

Comment: sorry for make things unclear, what i am looking for is this: https://jsfiddle.net/3fkqwej7/ , can your plugin do that? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, as stated in [the doc](https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight/#manual-calling-of-featherlight)...